# Can the same contestant represent their country in both Miss World and Miss universe?

Tags: miss-world, miss-universe

In India, [Femina Miss India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femina_Miss_India), selects the contestants for Miss World and Universe. They used to send the winner to Miss Universe and the runner-up to the Miss World contest, but changed it after 1994's Indian historic dual win. Now they select three different winners for each show.

But why do they enter different contestants in the two contests - is there some rule against using the same contestant? Or is it just to avoid scheduling conflicts?

Comment: Are real world contests on topic? Similar to sports no?

Comment: @cde He's not asking about who is running, he's asking about the mechanics of the competition. Personally, seems fine to me... it'd be the same as asking about the mechanics of any reality TV show, which we have several questions about.

Comment: @Catija Seems pretty similar to sports and news and other current events. I can't really see how this is on-topic simply because it's aired on TV. Reality TV shows are deliberately constructed as TV-shows. This is a real world contest that just so happens to also air on TV.

Comment: TV *show* seems like a rather fuzzy term.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic on basis of [community response on meta](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/scope-award-beauty-contest-shows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, they can *represent* their country in both contests but they **can not win** both.

So, if someone goes to the Miss World competition and loses, she can then also go to the Miss Universe competition.

However, if she were to win the Miss World competition, she would not later compete in the Miss Universe competition because her duties as Miss World would prevent her from winning, so they send the first runner-up to compete in her place instead.

Here's an actual [example](http://adobochronicles.com/2014/12/18/can-the-reigning-miss-world-also-become-miss-universe/):

> On December 14, 2014, Miss South Africa Rolene Strauss was crowned Miss World in London. But unlike in other countries, whomever is chosen Miss South Africa in any given year represents the country in  all major international beauty pageants, including Miss Universe, Miss International, Miss Supranational, Miss World and Miss Grand International.
>
> So, when the Miss Universe Pageant is held in Florida next month, Strauss will take to the stage as Miss South Africa, right? Wrong.
>
> Remember what the Miss Universe Pageant hosts always say before announcing the name of the new Miss Universe? “In the event that the new Miss Universe will not be able to fulfill her duties, the first runner-up will automatically  become Miss Universe.”
>
> Ergo, Strauss as the reigning Miss World can’t possibly fulfill her duties as Miss Universe which include traveling and appearing with Miss Universe Pageant owner Donald Trump. So Strauss has been disqualified from the Florida pageant.
>
> Miss South Africa’s 1st runner up, Ziphozakhe Zokufa will take over to represent her country in the Miss Universe Pageant.